# Operating a 12V camping fridge while batteries are charging

Tags: batteries, charger

I'm doing a camper build and have hooked up three 12V deep cycle batteries in parallel for my power source. I have a 12V ac/dc charger that is connected to a 1000W true sine wave inverter to charge the batteries while driving. basically the inverter turns on when the engine is running, supplying power to the charger to charge the batteries.

The problem I am having is, the 12V refrigerators electronic display starts going crazy when the batteries are charging. I'm "assuming" the charger is somehow causing this but I'm hoping there is a solution to allow me to charge the batteries and keep the fridge cold. It's a pain to have to try and remember to turn the fridge off and on every time we drive somewhere but I also don't want to fry the electronics on the fridge.

Refrigerator specs: 12V/ 24V DC. Rated power: 50 W. Energy consumption: 0.16 kWh/24 hrs. The charger has a top output of 7 amps at initial start up and then gradually drops down to 2 amps for the final top off. Not sure what else to put in here so if I'm missing any info that is important, please let me know. thank you.

Comment: Please, charge the batteries while driving from the engine's 12 V, not from an inverter+charger. Where's the inverter being powered from when the engine is running anyway?

Comment: @Neil_UK - I thought the setup was a bit Wil-e-Coyote like as well.

Comment: This is a mad science. You do convert 12VDC to 220VAC and then  back to 12VDC to charge the batteries?!! When it would be a simple solution to put an ideal diode or battery isolator from RV start battery.

Comment: Please Google for how to properly set up 12V electrics for an RV. Your current setup is unnecessarily complex and wastes energy. Use your RV’s alternator for charging your battery bank while drive or the engine is running and a separate battery charger when connected to utility power.

Comment: OK, some clarification. The batteries are AGM and I was made to understand that a vehicle alternator does not work well for AGM batteries, hence the inverter and charger. The inverter is connected to an electrical accessories panel that gets voltage when the key is on, so power is supplied when the engine is running. We don't plan on boondocking very much so I'm not planning on installing a solar panel system and wanted a charger I could use when plugged into shore power. This is on a 2016 sprinter and I am in the US so, of course it's Wil-E-Coyote like, that's what we do here.